# Filter non-mail items in New-MailboxExportRequest by date range

Tags: powershell, exchange-2010

I know I can filter mail items in a `New-MailboxExportRequest` using Received and Sent dates like so:

```
{
  (
    (Received -lt '04/01/2015') 
      -and (Received -ge '03/01/2015')
  ) -or (
    (Sent -lt '04/01/2015') 
      -and (Sent -ge '03/01/2015')
  )
}
```

However, I cannot find any date fields that correspond to other mailbox items such as calendar entries. How could I filter those items by date?

If it is not possible to filter these other items by date, will they be excluded whenever a date range is specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you can either Include or Exclude folders.
I think the dates specified apply to all items in the mailbox.

> The ExcludeFolders parameter specifies the list of folders to exclude
>   during the export.

Link: [New-MailboxExportRequest | technet.microsoft.com](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607299(v=exchg.150).aspx)

LE: Tested the cmdlet:

So I created today (09/28/2015): 
appointments for: yesterday (09/27/2015), today (09/28/2015), tomorrow (09/29/2015), 2 days from now (09/30/2015), 3 days from now (10/01/2015) 
tasks for: yesterday), today, tomorrow, 2 days from now

Afterwards, in EMS:

1. New-ManagementRoleAssignment –Role “Mailbox Import Export” –User “DOMAIN\USER”
2. Restarted EMS
3. New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox onpremise -ContentFilter {((Received -ge '09/28/2015') -and (Received -lt '09/29/2015'))} -FilePath "\cas2013\c$\onpremise_1.pst"
4. New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox onpremise -ContentFilter {((Sent -ge '09/28/2015') -and (Sent -lt '09/29/2015'))} -FilePath "\cas2013\c$\onpremise_2.pst"

Result: both .pst included everything created today

Comment: It is clear how this works for mail items. I am asking about *non* -mail items, such as calendar entries, notes, etc.

Comment: yes, but it also specifically asks about date range filters, and it is not clear to me how sent and received apply to calendar items, tasks, and notes (when then do not exist in messages). For instance, if a calendar items was created on 1/1/2015, will it be included in a search with a sent date range or received date range or both or neither?

Comment: Sorry, I messed with my previous comment somehow. This was it "I am not sure I get the question. It clearly states that you can Include(Exclude)Folders can be used to specify Calendar, Tasks and Notes folders. By choosing an option, it will get applied for the contained items". By checking the technet, I do not see any other property to use in such case: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff601762(v=exchg.150).aspx I will try to use it and come back  to you with my results.

Comment: thank you, if I had an Exchange instance to test on I would but I don't

Comment: So I created today (09/28/2015):
appointments for: yesterday (09/27/2015), today (09/28/2015), tomorrow (09/29/2015), 2 days from now (09/30/2015), 3 days from now (10/01/2015)
tasks for: yesterday), today, tomorrow, 2 days from now

Comment: Afterwards, in EMS:
1. New-ManagementRoleAssignment –Role “Mailbox Import Export” –User “DOMAIN\USER” 
2. Restarted EMS
3. New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox onpremise -ContentFilter {((Received -ge '09/28/2015') -and (Received -lt '09/29/2015'))} -FilePath "\\cas2013\c$\onpremise_1.pst"
4. New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox onpremise -ContentFilter {((Sent -ge '09/28/2015') -and (Sent -lt '09/29/2015'))} -FilePath "\\cas2013\c$\onpremise_2.pst"

Result: both .pst included everything created today

Comment: Thanks @m-adrian -- please update your answer with this information.